# Issue of it is removing all the query string after '-' is used in url

Tags: jquery, regex, url, url-rewriting

Here, I am removing query string from URL using regex in juery.
There are two checkboxes and as per requirement I am removing query string from URL has one of the checkbox being unchecked.

For e.g. my URL is like:

```
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?fuels=Gasoline&engines=Jet-Drive
```

Here if I want to remove query string 'engines' and want to remain 'fuels', it is working good and becoming url like :

```
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?fuels=Gasoline
```

But when my URL is like:

```
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?engines=Jet-Drive&fuels=Gasoline
```

And I want to remove string 'engines' and want to remain 'fuels', it removes all the query string and URL becomes like:

```
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord
```

As I want like:

```
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?engines=Jet-Drive
```

Here what I have tried is:

```
url.replace(new RegExp(key + "=\\w+"),"").replace("?&","?").replace("&&","&").split('-')[0];
```

And

```
new RegExp('[\?&]'+key+'=([^&#]*)').exec(url);

      let length = url.length;
      if(url.charAt(length-1)==='?')
      url = url.slice(0,length-1);

      if(url.charAt(length-1)==='&')
      url = url.slice(0,length-1);

      return url;
```

Please suggest what to do?

**Note: The URL is creating dynamically.**

Comment: Wouldn’t it be the `.split('-')[0];` that’s removing the “fuels”, etc rather than the regex ?

Comment: @racraman: If I don't use it, the URL becomes like,

`http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?-Drive&fuels=Gasoline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try the below code. It is very difficult to achieve your functionality with one regex but I tried to implement it with the following logic.

**Proposed procedure:**

```
1. Create a regex to capture the url in two groups.
2. Filter out the required query string by creating a dynamic regex containing your query string. That is if fuels checkbox is checked then create the regex with fuels string and when engine checkbox is checked then use engine inside the regex.
```

I used the below regexes:

```
(.*?\?)(.*) --> For seperating the url to two strings.
(fuels=[^\\s&]*) --> Dynamic regex for filtering out the required query.
```

You can find the implementation of the proposed procedure below:

```js
const string = `http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?engines=Jet-Drive1&fuels=Petrol
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?fuels=Petrol&engines=Jet-Drive2
http://localhost/boat/frontend/boat_listing/loadRecord?engines=Jet-Drive3&fuels=Gasolene`;
const regexp = /(.*?\?)(.*)/g;
const dynamicQueryString = "fuels"; // You can pass this string from the checked box directly.
const regex1 = new RegExp('(' + dynamicQueryString + '=[^\\s&]*)', 'g');
let resultString = "";
const matches = string.matchAll(regexp);
    
for (const match of matches) {
  let tempMatch = match[2].match(regex1);
  resultString = resultString.concat(match[1] + tempMatch[0] + "\n");
}
console.log(resultString);
```

Comment: Thanks, let me check but I forgot to mentioned that URL is creating dynamically. So, I added note to my question

Comment: Your code is working good. But I am wondering if I want to remove query string which I am passing then how could it be?

For e.g., you are passing 'fuels' and want to remove that query string.

Comment: That could also be done easily. Please see [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/ybpSZW/1) Once you get the second group you can do the same. Shall I add this in answer or you get it?